# How to convert an older XCode project

Tags: xcode

I originally created my XCode project with version 3.2.6 and it's moved through 4.x to 5.0. I only just realised that XCode 3.2.6 was still my default XCode and that new projects are .xcode rather than .xcodeproj.

Is there an easy way to update my project - or will XCode have done this and simply kept the old name?

Comment: Should just do it I think. I don't remember having had to do anything special before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Xcode project by Right click the .xcode file and click the open with option and choose the latest Xcode application.